# OpenStreetmap Multipolygon with Members without role

Tags: openstreetmap

I found this relation in OpenStreetMap

http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1561932

http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/1561932/full

It has only one outer member but it needs the other members to be a valid multipolygon. Is it common that Members without role are treated as outer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is **not** a valid multipolygon. The name is only written around the border, but not in the middle as I would expect for an area labelling.

And there is no kind of area fill color.

Comment: The lack of area fill colour is because it's a relation - the data view on osm.org doesn't construct areas. The lack of a label is because place areas aren't currently rendered on openstreetmap-carto

Answer (score 1):

This will be constructed into an area by most multipolygon parsers, which do not depend on inner or outer tags. It would be clearer if it had outer on all of its members, but is not required.